# Slax, connman — how to disable assigning IPv4-LL addresses?

Tags: connman

I want to build a custom image of Slax and I am particularly annoyed by all those link-local (IPv4-LL) addresses it assigns to all interfaces by default. How can I get rid of that? I can't find any clues in `man connman` and `man connman.conf`.

Comment: LL being 169.254.x.x? If you turn up an interface you need an IP. If dhcp tries to get an IP on an interface, it will fallback to LL. Same for most things that need an IP on an interface. So assign some other IP instead of the autogenerated LL?

Comment: Yes, those ones. I don't want it to assign link-local addresses, even in case DHCP assignment is failed. In that case, better leave interface without IP address at all. I did not find which program does that assignment and the last culprit must be `connman`; however, I am not actually sure, if anybody knows better, I am ready to learn. And no, it is possible to make interface physically up without any IP: just run `ip link set NIC up` without `ip addr add ...`.

Comment: I'm unaware of any software that uses APIPA (the LL addresses come from this feature). It is generally always dhclient or dhcpd.

Comment: Yes. But there is no (obvious) DHCP client running. "APIPA" (a.k.a. Zeroconf) is *not* DHCP, and ISC's `dhclient` [doesn't support it](https://serverfault.com/questions/419986/dhclient-and-link-local-address); for `dhcpcd` I know how to disable this. On the other side, `connman` README states it supports it and it is the only network configuration software appears to be running after booting Slax.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear. Only dhcp type behavior would do this, and connman certainly seems to be doing a dhcp request here: https://github.com/ev3dev/connman/blob/e2bb7e45a0e11001deeee61d83441b90965d35eb/gdhcp/client.c#L536

Comment: APIPA addresses *don't have anything to do* with DHCP requests. There is no server to control address assginments. The only thing it does in common with DHCP is checking if the randomly chosen address is already used in the network, by doing sending an ARP who-has; that is what the code is doing. The "dhcp_client" there is just the name of the variable, chosen unwisely. But, it proves `connman` itself does it, as I suspected. How do disable it entirely?

Comment: Not run connman? https://github.com/ev3dev/connman/blob/e2bb7e45a0e11001deeee61d83441b90965d35eb/tools/dhcp-test.c#L164 OR modify connman to not run a dhcp client?

Comment: Alternatively, remove the ip once assigned by connman.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I refer to [RFC3927](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3927) as IPv4LL, because connman does. Others call it link-local, bonjour or zeroconf.

First: yes, connman is probably the programm that is assigning those IPv4LL addresses.
For IPv4 Connman offers `[off|manual|auto]` settings. For IPv6 as well, so it seems to be kind of their philosophy to not offer seperate DHCP options.

Depending on why you want to get rid of those addresses, James answers in the comments probably are the simplest ones:

- Write a script: check if you got an 169.256.xx.xx address. If so, act accordningly (e.g. manually configure IP from connman).
- Switch to another network manager

Looking at the [source](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/connman/connman.git/tree/) files `client.c` and `dhcp.c`. As far as I can tell, connman does:

1. Try DHCP
2. Fall back to IPv4LL, if that failed

If you are able to apply patches to the connman source, locate `gdhcp/client.c`:

- Inside `ipv4ll_start(GDHCPClient *dhcp_client)` the IPv4LL address is generated
- Functions `ipv4ll_start` and `ipv4ll_start_client` should be a good starting point
- You know better than I what exactly to do there, as I lack details on your problem
- Only slightly related: I tested modifying `uint32_t arp_random_ip(void)` inside `src/shared/arp.c` to return a static IP and connman still works fine.
- So I guess, you could for example call `ipv4ll_stop` right inside `ipv4ll_start` or something like that.